# SWIFT - UIimagepicker to assign image into an array

Tags: arrays, xcode, uitableview, swift, uiimagepickercontroller

Basically I would like my Imagepicker to be able to assign the captured a image to a new row in tableview each time the user input a name and select a image for this name. I encounter at least 2 types of errors for below codes:

1) 'UIImageView' is not a subtype of 'NSString' error being displayed besides "cell.itemImage.image = UIImage(named: selectedImageArray[indexPath.row])"

2) a problem of how to access for example '.contentMode' and '.clipsToBounds' properties of the assigned image (being each in the array to be assigned to the tableview)

Appreciate anyone's help on these~~

Tableview Controller:

```
import UIKit

class AddPostItemTableViewController: UITableViewController, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate, UITableViewDelegate {

@IBOutlet var titleName: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var tapCamera: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet var tapLibrary: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var itemNameField:UITextField!

@IBOutlet weak var AddPostTableView:UITableView!

var selectedImageArray:[UIImageView!] = []
var selectedItemNameArray:[String!] = []

let tapCameraRec = UITapGestureRecognizer()
let tapLibraryRec = UITapGestureRecognizer()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    tapCameraRec.addTarget(self, action: "tappedCamera")
    tapLibraryRec.addTarget(self, action: "tappedLibrary")
    tapCamera.addGestureRecognizer(tapCameraRec)
    tapLibrary.addGestureRecognizer(tapLibraryRec)
    tapLibrary.userInteractionEnabled = true
    tapCamera.userInteractionEnabled = true

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}


override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

override func touchesBegan(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    self.view.endEditing(true)
    // Dismiss keyboard on touch
}

func tappedLibrary(){

    if itemNameField.text == "" {
        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Oops", message: "Please key in the name of item first", preferredStyle: .Alert)
        let doneAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Default, handler: nil)
        alertController.addAction(doneAction)

        self.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)

        return
    }

    else if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(.PhotoLibrary) {
        let imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
        imagePicker.allowsEditing = true
        imagePicker.delegate = self
        imagePicker.sourceType = .PhotoLibrary

        self.presentViewController(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}

func tappedCamera(){

    if itemNameField.text == "" {
        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Oops", message: "Please key in the name of item first", preferredStyle: .Alert)
        let doneAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Default, handler: nil)
        alertController.addAction(doneAction)

        self.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)

        return
    }

    else if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(.PhotoLibrary) {
        let imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
        imagePicker.allowsEditing = true
        imagePicker.delegate = self
        imagePicker.sourceType = .Camera

        self.presentViewController(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}

func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController!, didFinishPickingImage image:UIImageView!, editingInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject]!) {
    selectedImageArray.append(image)
    selectedImageArray.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFill
    selectedImageArray.clipsToBounds = true

    selectedItemNameArray.append(itemNameField!.text)

    dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}

// MARK: - Table view data source

override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    // #warning Potentially incomplete method implementation.
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
{
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
        return self.selectedItemNameArray.count
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath:
    NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cellIdentifier = "ItemCell"
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellIdentifier, forIndexPath:
            indexPath) as AddPostTableViewCell

        // Configure the cell...
        cell.itemName.text = selectedItemNameArray[indexPath.row]
        cell.itemImage.image = UIImage(named: selectedImageArray[indexPath.row])

        return cell
}
```

Tableview Cell:

```
import UIKit

class AddPostTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

@IBOutlet weak var itemName:UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var itemImage:UIImageView!

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    // Initialization code
}

override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

    // Configure the view for the selected state
}

}
```

Comment: This is a ton of code ... to get the answers you are looking for, you might want to break this up into two separate questions and limit the code on each to the code that is relevant to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first error suggests that your array contains UIImageViews, not names of images. The UIImage(imageNamed: ) accepts name of image as a string. You probably need something like

```
cell.itemImage.image = selectedImageArray[indexPath.row].image
```

or if you want to use the UIImage(imageNamed:), use your name array instead.

With regards to the second issue, you can put a dot after the [indexPath.row] to access properties of the stored object at the given index like I did above. Or you can do it in a more readable way:

```
var myImage = selectedImageArray[indexPath.row]
myImage.someProperty
```